# psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have some bulk postgresql 9.3.9 data inserts I do in python 3.4. I've been using SQLAlchemy which works fine for normal data processing. For a while I've been using psycopg2 so as to utilize the `copy_from` function which I found faster when doing bulk inserts. The issue I have is that when using `copy_from`, the bulk inserts fail when I have data that has got some `special` characters in it. When I remove the highlighted line the insert runs successfully.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/apps/data_script/data_update.py", line 1081, 
  in copy_data_to_db
    'surname', 'other_name', 'reference_number', 'balance'), sep="|", null='None')
psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  
COPY source_file_raw, line 98: "94|1|99|2015-09-03 10:17:34|False|True|John|Doe|A005-001\008020-01||||||..."
```

**Code producing the error**

```
cursor.copy_from(data_list, 'source_file_raw', 
columns=('id', 'partner_id', 'pos_row', 'loaded_at', 'has_error', 
         'can_be_loaded', 'surname', 'other_name', 'reference_number', .............), 
         sep="|", null='None')
```

**The db connection**

```
    import psycopg2
    pg_conn_string = "host='%s' port='%s' dbname='%s' user='%s' password='%s'" 
    %(con_host, con_port, con_db, con_user, con_pass)
    conn = psycopg2.connect(pg_conn_string)
    conn.set_isolation_level(0)
    if cursor_type == 'dict':
        cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    else:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor
```

So the baffling thing is that SQlAlchemy can do the bulk inserts even when those "special characters" are present but using psycopg2 directly fails. Am thinking there must be a way for me to escape this or to tell psycopg2 to find a smart way to do the insert or am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: `0x00` is the null byte, and is *never* permitted in text strings in PostgreSQL (or most systems).

Comment: Understood. However, using SQLAlchemy I don't get the error. So, I don't get it. Does SQLAlchemy escape the null byte?

Comment: Test and see what it does. Insert from sqlalchemy then select from psql to see what it did. I would not be surprised to see it silently truncate the data.